# How to get background image to 100vh on smaller screens but 50vh on large screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Learning bootstrap, I am trying to make a hero section on my website where if you are on the large screen breakpoint, the background image on the hero section will be 50% of the web page, but on smaller screens it will change to 100% of the webpage.

I think the problem lies with me setting height:50vh, I just simply don't know what to write on the bootstrap portion where if the screen switches to small, the height becomes 100.

Thank you!

```css
.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(118, 118, 121, 0.432), rgba(82, 76, 80, 0.73)), url('https://via.placeholder.com/800/ff0000');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="bg-image p-5 text-light ">
  <div class="container text-center pt-5 h-100 ">
    <h1 class="m-5">I Need Help </h1>
    <button class="btn-primary rounded-pill">Book Us</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please accept an answer so other know the question is resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries. In your CSS file, at whatever screen size you want you can add -

```
@media screen(min-height: the_height_you_want) {
    .bg-image {
        height: 50vh;
    }
}
```

For more details on media queries, you should see this tutorial - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's small (sm) breakpoint is at screen widths less than `768px`. You can use a media query for this...

```
.bg-image {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bg-image {
        height: 50vh;
    }
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/wvMY8zAx9H